# How to open login URL with SafariViewController with angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: keycloak, capacitor, ionic6, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm new to angular-oauth2-oidc. I want to show login page from keycloak service for my Ionic 6 mobile project in embedded browser with Capacitor browser plugin. I've used loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin from angular-oauth2-oidc to display my login page and it works with external browser but it didn't meet requirement for IOS.

Anyone have any idea how to implement login page in embedded browser with loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin?

I tried: Open login page with loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin with embedded browser in Capacitor browser plugin.

Comment: Hello at stack**overflow**. (Can you get help with English?)